# How can I prevent my app from crashing when using Google AdMob, possibly due to issues with the layout parameters?

Tags: android, layout, admob

I've integrated Google AdMob into my app, but it's causing my app to crash. I suspect that the problem might be related to the layout configuration.

Here's what the issue looks like:
[image: AdMob Crash]

Here's the relevant code for setting up the AdView and game view:

```java
private AdView createAdView() {
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID_BANNER);
    adView.setId(12345); 
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    adView.setLayoutParams(params);
    adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    return adView;
}

private View createGameView(AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg) {
    gameView = initializeForView(new SGame(this), cfg);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, adView.getId());
    gameView.setLayoutParams(params);
    return gameView;
}
```

I suspect that the issue might be related to the layout parameters. Can someone provide guidance on how to prevent the app from crashing when using Google AdMob, especially with regard to layout configuration?

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Maybe I'm not seeing it.  What do you mean by it's "crushing" your app?  Looking at the screenshot it looks like I'm seeing double vision, however.  Is it a 3D game or something?

Comment: the application is compressed, I want the advertising to be in the foreground ,in the 2 pictures you can see that the one that contains advertising is restricted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, ok.  Well, you do have the game view below the ad view.  This means it will occupy the region below the ad view and it will be shorter since there's less vertical space for it to occupy.  You can probably change:  params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, adView.getId()); to instead align with the parent top.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1. Create a FrameLayout that hosts your 2 views and plave the AdView second (ie above) the GameView.
2. Create a vertical LinearLayout that hold an AdContainer (in which you place you AdView) and a GameContainer (in which you place your GameView). You can actually simplify this somewhat, but the above gets the concept across cleanly.